# Higher AR Power weilding poke moveset weapons?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I love using two weapons that both poke the target at the same time with a really quick poke. Kind of like two rapiers do. When Helix and other halberds were out, I fell in love with that. Now there is a void in my heart. I need two weapons, with massive AR and scaling, that have long range and fast poke. So far the best thing I came up with, was two spit-firespears. Is there anything better? Assume i have 99 dex and str.

Comment: What's wrong with the Helix spears and Rapiers?

Comment: I don't know about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on play style really.

Spears have a huge range, with the downside of having a "sweet spot". For example, the Helix Spear can deal a whopping crit damage (I think ~400 base damage) if you hit them with the tip of the spear at full extension, while hitting them close range will drop the damage quite significantly.

One the other hand, rapiers have a shorter range, but don't have a "sweet spot" like spears do; and have the ability to parry.

Ricard's Rapier has a neat R2 that deals a succession of quick jabs, dealing decent damage and staggering the enemy as well.

Answer (score 0):

+10 Stone Spears For the range and they seem to have a fairly quick attack. anywhere between 600-900 for a LB combo